# How to fit Keras ImageDataGenerator for large data sets using batches

Tags: python, keras, data-augmentation

I want to use the Keras ImageDataGenerator for data augmentation.
To do so, I have to call the .fit() function on the instantiated ImageDataGenerator object using my training data as parameter as shown below.

```
image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(featurewise_center=True, rotation_range=90)
image_datagen.fit(X_train, augment=True)
train_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory('data/images')
model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=2000, epochs=50)
```

However, my training data set is too large to fit into memory when loaded up at once.
Consequently, I would like to fit the generator in several steps using subsets of my training data.

Is there a way to do this?

One potential solution that came to my mind is to load up batches of my training data using a custom generator function and fitting the image generator multiple times in a loop. However, I am not sure whether the fit function of ImageDataGenerator can be used in this way as it might reset on each fitting approach.

As an example of how it might work:

```
def custom_train_generator():
    # Code loading training data subsets X_batch
    yield X_batch


image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(featurewise_center=True, rotation_range=90)
gen = custom_train_generator()

for batch in gen:
    image_datagen.fit(batch, augment=True)

train_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory('data/images')
model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=2000, epochs=50)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**NEWER TF VERSIONS** (`>=2.5`):

ImageDataGenerator() has been deprecated in favour of :

> tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory

An example usage from the documentation:

```
  tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory,
    labels='inferred',
    label_mode='int',
    class_names=None,
    color_mode='rgb',
    batch_size=32,
    image_size=(256, 256),
    shuffle=True,
    seed=None,
    validation_split=None,
    subset=None,
    interpolation='bilinear',
    follow_links=False,
    crop_to_aspect_ratio=False,
    **kwargs
)
```

**OLDER TF VERSIONS** (`<2.5`)

`ImageDataGenerator()` provides you with the possibility of loading the data into batches; You can actually use in your `fit_generator()` method the parameter **batch_size**, which works with `ImageDataGenerator()`; there is no need (only for good practice if you want) to write a generator from scratch.

IMPORTANT NOTE:

Starting from TensorFlow 2.1, `.fit_generator()` has been deprecated and you should use `.fit()`

Example taken from Keras official documentation:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

# compute quantities required for featurewise normalization
# (std, mean, and principal components if ZCA whitening is applied)
datagen.fit(x_train)

# TF <= 2.0
# fits the model on batches with real-time data augmentation:
model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32),
                    steps_per_epoch=len(x_train) // 32, epochs=epochs)

#TF >= 2.1
model.fit(datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32),
         steps_per_epoch=len(x_train) // 32, epochs=epochs)
```

I would suggest reading this excellent article about ImageDataGenenerator and Augmentation: https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-configure-image-data-augmentation-when-training-deep-learning-neural-networks/

The solution to your problem lies in this line of code(either simple flow or flow_from_directory):

```
# prepare iterator
it = datagen.flow(samples, batch_size=1)
```

For creating your own DataGenerator, one should have a look at this link(for a starting point): [https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly](https://stanford.edu/%7Eshervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly)

IMPORTANT NOTE (2):

If you use Keras from Tensorflow (Keras inside Tensorflow), then for both the code presented and the tutorials you consult, ensure that you replace the import/neural network creation snippets:

```
from keras.x.y.z import A
```

WITH

```
from tensorflow.keras.x.y.z import A
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the article! I see, fitting the image generator itself is not always needed so I can omit it and therefore I do not need to load up my whole x_train. Howevert, I read that for some augmentation operations (e.g. scaling) I have to use .fit() on the image data generator before being able to call .flow() or .flow_from_directory(). Is there a way to use `datagen.fit(x_train)` without having to load the whole x_train at once?

Comment: I have the same question as @C.S. Any way to do what he asked?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. You can created your own DataGenerator(subclassing tensorflow.keras.utils.Sequence) and apply the image augmentations at a batch level. A good starting point is this link: https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly

Comment: @TimbusCalin  How could you load and augment images when pixels are already present in the Dataframe like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59596784/custom-imagedatagenerator-for-half-a-million-images-where-labels-and-pixels-ar)? Could you please answer it there?